# Dropdown from list of keywords how to change visual part of option value

Tags: php, twig

I have part of TWIG code

```
{% for keyword in keywords %}
<option value="{{ keyword }}">{{ keyword }}</option>
```

what takes values from /config.ini where

```
keywords = ">Austria,>Belgium,>Canada"
```

So as a result I have HTML dropdown list of keywords like

```
>Austria
>Belgium
>Canada
```

Is there a simple way to show visible part of dropdown list without '>' ? I mean only that relates to

```
{{ keyword }}</option>
```

from TWIG code above.

May be I can do something with /config.ini to write values there like

```
keywords = ">Austria=Austria,>Belgium=Belgium,>Canada=Canada"
```

but what syntax could be then to use instead of ?

```
<option value="{{ keyword }}">{{ keyword }}</option>
```

Thanks for any ideas to try.

Comment: I think it makes most sense to change your config to `keywords = "Austria,Belgium,Canada"`

Comment: It's natural, but unfortunately it affects too much of other changes associated with keyword list and functions. So I'm looking for a way to adjust a visible part only.

Comment: Well I think it's ugly but you could just remove it in twig `<option value="{{ keyword|slice(1) }}">{{ keyword|slice(1) }}</option>`

Comment: Yes, it works ! But due to other functions I changed only visible part `<option value="{{ keyword }}">{{ keyword|slice(1) }}</option>` and it does not ugly at all ! I was looking for a trick - and this is the trick ! If you wish - please, publish as an answer and I'll mark it as a right one !